# array overbounding using a loop?

Tags: c, arrays

ok so i really dont know what to add to this question title but the problem i have might be a small one

```
int i;
char ch[3];

for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    ch[i] = (0x60|i)+1;
}

printf("%s %d\n", ch, i);
printf("address \n\ti %p\n\tch %p\n", &i, &ch);
```

and the output to this is

```
abce 101
address 
    i 0xbfc6bd4c
    ch 0xbfc6bd49
```

so the problem i have is that why does the letted 'd' get skipped

after thinking for a while for why does the string also get termenated im assuming that int i variable is located after ch variable, i is 4 bytes long i's first byte gets replaced by the letter 'e' i guess that the rest of the 3 bytes are filled with 0000 0000 thus causing the string to terminate, is this correct ??

**EDIT**

so i seem to have gotten another question why doesn't the loop also get continued and write to variable i's memory space

Comment: You're writing 10 items into an array of size 3.

Comment: @interjay yes that was intentional im just trying to understand how things work, now that i think about it why doesn't the rest of i's bytes also get replaced

Comment: STOP doing intentionally bad things and then asking what is happening.  It's UB, that's it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because seeks to have, (intentional), UB explained.

Comment: @MartinJames hmm ok then thanks.

Comment: I am sitting on a bough of a tree, sawing it off on the trunk side. I thought I should break my neck when I hit the ground, but I was surprised to find I have only sawn off my leg. Explain.

Comment: @WeatherVane [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnosia) i do not think that this is the exact case for i do not have any knowledge about how the human brain work nor have other relevant medical knowledge, the person also seems to have the inability to feel pain also he was capable of climbing a tree with a saw and capable of operating the saw while on a bough of a tree and was capable of creating a imaginary scenery of what would be the consequences of his actions so he seems to posses good motor function, direct this question to a relative field knowledge you should get a better answer

Answer (score 1):

The loop stops shortly after you go out of bounds because when you overwrite `i`, it no longer fits the `i < 10` criteria for the loop to continue. This happens when `i` is 4, it sets the first byte of `i` to `(0x60 | 4) + 1`, which is `101`. 
Which is what you then see when you print `i`, because this is the low-order byte of the `int`.

Comment: ah yes thanks that makes seance for why the loop stops